# Shell script to get device ID

Tags: shell, head

Ok guys, I'm stumped here.  Below is a chunk of script that is designed to identify a device by name and print the tty information it's hooked to.  Since there can be more than one of these devices hooked up at any time, I need to select the lowest numbered interface.  Once I lick this part I'll define the output as a variable and use the output to run a hamlib script so my rig can communicate with the computer.

Anyway, I can't seem to find a good way to capture ONLY the first line.  I've tried head, awk, sed in just about any kind of iteration I could think of, and the output either gives me two lines of output, or no output at all.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
(
    syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
    devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
    [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
    eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
    [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
    echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL" | grep CP2105 | sort | uniq | cut -b 6-12 |
head -1
)
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
floridomd@GE72VR-7RF:~$ ./port-testing.sh
ttyUSB1
ttyUSB2
```

What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: `ONLY the first line` sooo `for ...... done | head -n1` ?

Comment: This works.  However, my goal is not to simply 'echo' the information--the 'echo' is just there for testing.  I need to define the output as a variable so that I can use it in a command string.  Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

> to capture ONLY the first line
>
> I need to define the output as a variable

So just get first line and put it in a variable.

```
variable=$(
    find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev |
    while IFS= read -r sysdevpath; do
       ....
    done | head -n1
)
```

Notes:

- `echo "" | sort | uniq` - is strange - why sort and uniq only one line? It's not like one line with change position.
- `echo "" | grep` not inside an `if` is also strange. Just use an `if`. You seem to want `if [[ "$ID_SERIAL" == CP2105 ]]; then echo "$devname"; fi`
- `for ...; do ( stuff ); done` is also strange, but justified - your `eval` the output of `udevadm` here. I think I would make it more visible:

  ```
  for ...; do
    (
       stuff
    )
  done
  ```
- `for i in $(...)` is an **antipattern**. Do not do it. Instead, you seem to want `find ... | while IFS= read -r sysdevpath; do` or `for sysdevpath in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/**/dev`.
- Use `if cmd1; then cmd2; fi`s instead of `cmd1 && cmd2` for readability and maintainability and consistent exit status (thinking of `set -e`).
- Also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .
- Check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: So just get first line and put it in a variable.

    variable=$(
        find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev |
        while IFS= read -r sysdevpath; do
           ....
        done | head -n1
    )

Comment: So just get first line and put it in a variable.

    variable=$(
        find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev |
        while IFS= read -r sysdevpath; do
           ....
        done | head -n1
    )


This worked like a champ.  Thanks.


    echo "" | sort | uniq - is strange - why sort and uniq only one line? It's not like one line with     change position.

These devices actually DO change position depending on which one gets picked up first upon boot.  I need to be able to choose the lowest numbered tty port of the applicable device.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: So you seem to want `for ..... done | sort | uniq | head -n1` - sort the output from the whole loop. Or alternatively `find .... | sort | uniq | while IFS= read -r line; ... done | head -n1` - sort before the loop.